# componentWillMount is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version 0.54.0 in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I use the react native latest version of 0.54.0 and Whenever run the apps on iOS there is found warning about deprecate the lifecycle methods. and also please update the components.

**Warning :**

**componentWillMount is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version. Use componentDidMount instead. As a temporary workaround, you can rename to UNSAFE_componentWillMount.
Please update the following components: Container, Text, TouchableOpacity, Transitioner, View**

I Have also change according to the waring add prefix UNSAFE_ each of the method.

```
UNSAFE_componentDidMount() {
}
UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
}
UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
}
UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
}
```

Although the warning continue. Please help me.

Currently I have hide the YellowBox waring in my Apps.

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';

render() {

  YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
    'Warning: componentWillMount is deprecated',
    'Warning: componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated',
  ]);
}
```

Comment: I use `componentWillMount` in my SSR web app as well... there seems to be discussions about adding in a `componentWillServerRender` (will prob be named something else)
https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/8/files/fe1c7bf56d792328a4c554fc51f80bc3503b995b#diff-6aaaf484b3a1d656cf6d95ee5dfbfd97

So one alternative might be to hold off with upgrading until the dust has settled then swapping over to the new hooks? (If they get added... if not. panic again I guess)

Answer (score 41):

You should move all the code from the componentWillMount to the constructor or componentDidMount.

> componentWillMount() is invoked just before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore calling setState() synchronously in this method will not trigger an extra rendering. Generally, we recommend using the constructor() instead.
>   Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method. For those use cases, use componentDidMount() instead.
>   This is the only lifecycle hook called on server rendering.
>
> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.
>   This method is a good place to set up any subscriptions. If you do that, don’t forget to unsubscribe in componentWillUnmount().
>   Calling setState() in this method will trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser updates the screen. This guarantees that even though the render() will be called twice in this case, the user won’t see the intermediate state. Use this pattern with caution because it often causes performance issues. It can, however, be necessary for cases like modals and tooltips when you need to measure a DOM node before rendering something that depends on its size or position.

[From the official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount)

Comment: I don't have any epxlicit place with `componentWillMount`, but I do have in my `app.js` a line of code after the constructor with `state={ tabindex:0 }`  How do I "move" that into the constructor?

Comment: `constructor(props) {super(props); this.state = { tabindex:0 }}`

Answer (score 16):

`componentDidMount` isn't deprecated and is definitely still safe to use, so there's no need to add `UNSAFE_` to that method. The componentWill*Something* methods are the ones that seem to be on their way out. Instead of `componentWillMount`, use a constructor for the stuff that doesn't produce side-effects, and use `componentDidMount` for the stuff that does.

Answer (score 8):

You should avoid using `componentWillSomething` in order to use `constructor` or `componentDidMount`

**However**, You have to be very carefully which one you'll use. A typical scenario is when you want to display a loading (using states) immediately after you open a screen

```
this.setState({ isLoading: true });
...
this.setState({ isLoading: false});
```

In this kind of case you have to use `componentDidMount` in order to set states. This is what React said about `constructors`

> Typically, in React constructors are only used for two purposes:
>
> 1. Initializing local state by assigning an object to this.state.
> 2. Binding event handler methods to an instance.
>
> You should not call setState() in the constructor(). Instead, if your component needs to use localstate, assign the initial state to this.state directly in the constructor.

Good coding!