# React, The function does not load data

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

How to rewrite the function so that it is updated and loaded every time you change pages. The fact is that the loading function works only on one page, but it does not pass to others, how to change it?

```
function loadModel(model) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch(moveToPending(model))

    const resource = require(`../resources/${model}`)
    const resourceActions = bindActionCreators(resource.actions, dispatch)
    const toaster = new Toaster(dispatch)

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resourceActions[getFunctionName(model)]()
        .then(res => {
          resolve(model)
          dispatch(resolveSubscriptions(model))
        })
        .catch(err => {
          if (debug) console.error(err)
          reject({ ...err, model })
          dispatch(resolveSubscriptions(model))
          toaster.error(`Could not load ${model}!`)
        })
      })
  }
}
```

Update.
Here's the componentWillMount(), I already have it, what do I need to add to it?

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.actions.subscribe(this.subscriptions)
      .then(() => {
        this.props.actions.fetchRegisters({year: this.state.currentYear, month: defaultMonths()})
          .then(() => {
            if (!this.props.registers.length) {
              this.toaster.warning('There is no data for charts')
            }
            this.createReportState()
          })
      })
  }
```

Comment: How you calling it `loadModel`?

Comment: Sorry, you can rephrase the question, I don't really understand what you want to hear.

Answer (score 0):

React has some lifecycle methods. You can use `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` for this purpose. You can pass this function as a prop to other pages and there you  can call it in `componentWillMount`, something like:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.loadModel(//arg);
}
```

For reference: [Component life-cycle methods](https://engineering.musefind.com/react-lifecycle-methods-how-and-when-to-use-them-2111a1b692b1)

Comment: you should refrain from using componentWillMount to load data -> see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206280/componentwillmount-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-next-major-version-0 for reference

Comment: This did not help me get the data on the page.