# How to assign a value to the state with a promise prior to the render method executing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, es6-promise, es6-class

EDIT:

[Here is a working jsComplete](https://jscomplete.com/playground/s267152) (use chrome) where I am assigning the JSON to the state instead making the api call. I am trying to do the same thing with the api call though.

How do I assign the value to the state property `locoData` before the `render()`  method runs?

`locoData` never gets assigned, and the `console.log(resp.data);` executes after the render method. I am new to react, and just catching up with the newer features in JavaScript such as promises, and this is really confusing me. I am executing this code in [jsComplete](https://jscomplete.com/playground)

If I assign the JSON to the state instead of trying to use the `axios.get` method, it works fine. JSON response is at the bottom.

I removed my bing map key.

```
  const LocationData = (props) => (
    <div>
      {props.location => <Location key={location.traceId} {...location}/>}
    </div>
)

class Location extends React.Component {    
    state = { locoData: {} },   
    const a = axios.get("https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?CountryRegion=US&adminDistrict=WA&locality=Somewhere&postalCode=98001&addressLine=100%20Main%20St.&key=bingMapKey").then(resp => { 
      console.log(resp.data);
      this.setState({ locoData: resp.data });  
    });

  render() {     
    resources = this.state.locoData.resourceSets[0].resources.map(function(resource){      
      return <div className="resource" key={resource.name} {...resource}></div>;
    });
    return (
        <div>
          <img src={location.brandLogoUri} />
        <div>
          <div>{resources.name}</div>
          <div>{resources[0].props.point.coordinates[0]} {resources[0].props.point.coordinates[1]}</div>
        </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    location: [],
  };
  displayLocation = (locationData) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        location: [...prevState.location, locationData],
    }));
  };
    render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <div>{this.props.title}</div>
        <Location LocationData={this.state.location} />
        </div>
    );
  } 
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App title="Simple Weather App" />,
  mountNode,
);

{"authenticationResultCode":"ValidCredentials","brandLogoUri":"http:\/\/dev.virtualearth.net\/Branding\/logo_powered_by.png","copyright":"Copyright © 2019 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.","resourceSets":[{"estimatedTotal":1,"resources":[{"__type":"Location:http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/search\/local\/ws\/rest\/v1","bbox":[47.275809008582883,-122.25881456692279,47.283534443724236,-122.24363249293789],"name":"100 Main St, Algona, WA 98001","point":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[47.279671726153559,-122.25122352993034]},"address":{"addressLine":"100 Main St","adminDistrict":"WA","adminDistrict2":"King County","countryRegion":"United States","formattedAddress":"100 Main St, Algona, WA 98001","locality":"Algona","postalCode":"98001"},"confidence":"High","entityType":"Address","geocodePoints":[{"type":"Point","coordinates":[47.279671726153559,-122.25122352993034],"calculationMethod":"InterpolationOffset","usageTypes":["Display"]},{"type":"Point","coordinates":[47.279653371643015,-122.25128403728938],"calculationMethod":"Interpolation","usageTypes":["Route"]}],"matchCodes":["Good"]}]}],"statusCode":200,"statusDescription":"OK","traceId":"591320e018b0476cbbe71f338ecab555|BN1EAE8F4E|7.7.0.0|Ref A: 3983F574345D41A782020BC15BA6BF08 Ref B: BN3EDGE0210 Ref C: 2019-05-04T04:30:29Z"}
```

Comment: Hi, I think better you make your request using lifeCicle `componentDidMount`. Inside de render() you have `resources`, but that variable never was declared. Another good tip is Try use destructor, for state and props.

Comment: Also look into conditional rendering to only render elements/components once the data has loaded. https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: the best solution here to use is conditional rendering with a loader.

Comment: @JuniusL.is there somewhere you can point me to that has an example, I don't entirely understand what that means.

Comment: see this little example I've created https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ukpsej

Comment: @JuniusL. thanks, it will take me a bit to digest that.

Comment: `use chrome` - why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use conditional rendering, have a variable set to true like `state = { isLoading: true }` once you receive data from the api, you set it to false.

[conditional rendering tutorial](https://www.robinwieruch.de/conditional-rendering-react/)

```
class Location extends React.Component {
  state = { locoData: {}, isLoading: true, errorMessage: "" };

  getDataFromApi = () => {
    const t_his = this;
    const a = axios
      .get(
        "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?CountryRegion=US&adminDistrict=WA&locality=Somewhere&postalCode=98001&addressLine=100%20Main%20St.&key=bingMapKey"
      )
      .then(resp => {
        console.log(resp.data);
        t_his.setState({ locoData: resp.data, isLoading: false });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        t_his.setState({
          errorMessage: "Error occured with status: " + error.response.status,
          isLoading: false
        });
      });
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getDataFromApi();
  };

  render() {

    const resourcesData =
      (this.state.locoData &&
        this.state.locoData.resourceSets &&
        this.state.locoData.resourceSets[0].resources) ||
      [];

    const resources = resourcesData.map(function(resource) {
      return <div className="resource" key={resource.name} {...resource} />;
    });

    const name = (resources && resources[0] && resources[0].props.name) || "";
    const coordinates =
      (resources && resources[0] && resources[0].props.point.coordinates[0]) ||
      "";
    const coordinates1 =
      (resources && resources[0] && resources[0].props.point.coordinates[1]) ||
      "";

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.isLoading ? (
          <Loader type="Puff" color="#00BFFF" height="100" width="100" />
        ) : (
          <div>
            {!!this.state.errorMessage ? (
              <h2>{this.state.errorMessage}</h2>
            ) : (
              <div>
                <img src={this.state.locoData.brandLogoUri} />
                <div>
                  <div>{name}</div>
                  <div>
                    {coordinates} {coordinates1}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7hxhlq)

Comment: Awesome, I created a Loader class for the condition, and this works perfectly, and I see what you are doing here with the conditional state property, and using it in the render() return. Now on to the next part to use the NOAA api to pass the coordinates in and get the current weather. Then I am going to add inputs for the user to enter an address. I thought this would be a good challenge to practice what I am learning. Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the correct answer to your problem.
React has a render cycle that you can find here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?utm_source=caibaojian.com
Or
 
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

You can do that in two ways the first one is using the function

```
 componentWillMount(){
    //Here you can set state normally
    }
```

that is ran before the component Is mount.
The second solution is using the new feature of react hooks using that, in this case, is the same as componentWillMount

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    //here you can set your state
  }
}, [])
```

**PS:** **Just use hooks, the old react cycle is deprecated**

Comment: I have tried using `componentWillMount()` with no success. I will read up on your links.

Comment: what is resp.data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206280/componentwillmount-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-next-major-version-0

Comment: @Gianmarco that's a  response

Comment: oh, so use just hooks

Comment: @Gianmarco the JSON from the resp.data is in the bottom of the question, I also updated the question with jsComplete.com where I use the JSON instead of the api call, which works, but not what I need.

Comment: you don't need hooks here.

Comment: @JuniusL. thanks for the link about the deprecated method.

Comment: and also it's hard for us suggest a solution if we don't know what's being returned from the api.

Comment: @JuniusL. the JSON from the api is at the bottom of the question. Here is an example that just uses the JSON, instead of the api call https://jscomplete.com/playground/s267152

Comment: @Gianmarco Thanks for the input, but conditional rendering was the solution. I am still going to read up on hooks though as it looks like something I will need to know and understand. It was mentioned in the course I was taking on pluralsight.