# What is the proper/right way to use Async Storage?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am a react-native newbie.

I'm trying to use Async Storage in my application.
I want the async storage to store token when user log in, it will navigate to homescreen. At homescreen, im trying to get the token through async storage and print it on console but all i get is promise. I just want to know what is the proper way to use Async storage especially in storing token? I know the alternative for this problem is using Redux state management, but I'm trying to learn the basic method.

I've tried to store the token in a variable in ComponentWillMount(), but it still does not work.

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    token = getToken();
  }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    console.log(token);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text> HomeScreen </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const getToken = async () => {
  let token = "";
  try {
    token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  return token;
};
```

Comment: `getToken` is `async` so it has not yet returned when you attempt to console.log it

Comment: Hi, so what is the proper to get the token so I could print the token in console ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I should note that `componentWillMount` is deprecated and you can use `constructor` or `componentDidMount` instead.

if you log token in `getToken` and after getting it, it will work fine. if you want to check if the user is logged in, you can do like this

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};

    getToken().then((token)=>{
       console.log(token)
       //check if user is logged in
    })
}
```

or you can do this in `componentDidMount`.
I hope this can help you

Comment: Which document does the componentWillMount not use? Can you link me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213753/6744400 and https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

Answer (score 0):

You should use it something like this,

```
import { AsyncStorage, Text, View, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

  //for storing Data

   setName = (value) => {
      AsyncStorage.setItem('name', value);
      this.setState({ 'name': value });
   }


//for Retrieving Data

 componentDidMount = () => AsyncStorage.getItem('name').then((value) => this.setState({ 'name': value }))
```

Here it is another [simple example](https://gist.github.com/pradeep1991singh/60f8ee10975307f908f4912cf6996e97).

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use it with Async and await**

```
setValue: function (key, value) {
    AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value)
},

getValue: async (key) => {
    let value = '';
    try {
        value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key) || 'none';
    } catch (error) {
        // Error retrieving data
        console.log(error.message);
    }
    return value;
}
```