# react-native react-nagivation-drawer keeps opening by default on App startup

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I'm sorry for the what might turn out to be a very stupid question, but for some time now I'm struggling with the following issue, but I'm new to react-native. 
I create a react-native app in which I implement the react-navigation-drawer navigation precisely as in the example.
What happens is that whenever I open the App the drawer is opened. The same things happens when i copy and paste the example from here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html

This makes me think I'm missing something with the dependencies. I've upgraded all i could think of from the needed librabries. My CPU is not a good one so I'm using my Android phone for testing.

I also get the warning "componentWillMount has been renamed..." when i use the react-navigation-drawer.

If you could help guide me to some information that would be helpful!
Thank you all in advance!

Below is some code for an example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, Header, Image, View, ScrollView, Alert, TouchableWithoutFeedback, TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight, StyleSheet  } from 'react-native';
import {Button, Icon, ThemeProvider} from 'react-native-elements';

import {createAppContainer, DrawerNavigator, withNavigation} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {createDrawerNavigator, DrawerActions, DrawerLayoutAndroid} from 'react-navigation-drawer';
.....
const Screen1PageScreenStack = createStackNavigator({
    Screen1Page: {
        screen: Screen1Page,
    }
},{
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        initialRouteName: 'Screen1Page',
        headerMode: 'screen',
        drawerLabel: 'HOME',
        drawerBackgroundColor: '#0000FF',
    }
)
});

const Screen2PageScreenStack = createStackNavigator({
    Screen2Page: {
        screen: Screen2Page,
    }
},{
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        initialRouteName: 'Screen2Page',
        headerMode: 'screen',
        drawerLabel: 'Categories',

    }
),
});

const appNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
Screen1Page: {
    name: 'Screen1PageScreenStack',
    screen: Screen1PageScreenStack,
},
Screen2Page: {
    name: 'Screen2PageScreenStack',
    screen: Screen2PageScreenStack,
}
});



const MyDrawerStrugglesApp = createAppContainer(appNavigator);
export default MyDrawerStrugglesApp ;
```

Comment: Can you please reproduce your code here, so that it could be easy to help ?

Comment: Have you tried my answer below ?

Comment: I did and unfortunately what it does is it just hides the Label of the menu from the drawer. But the drawer is still there and is opened above the rest of the app. :(

Comment: Try to redefine your stack and drawer like in this example : https://jsfiddle.net/fte9sp2b/
.
Also try to open your drawer with `onClick` of any hamburger menu button instead of using default swiping gesture

Comment: Still no luck. Though if I come up with a decent solution I will let you know!
Thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't give you a helpful solution

Comment: @amrs-tech So, the problem was with the fact I had to test the app on my phone, due to not having enough CPU. So i could test i had to shake the phone so I can get the debugging menu where i had to click on Reload. What happened was that I got so sick of it that I decided to generate a release APK so I can be definitely sure it's the testing environment that was causing the issue. And YES! That was the problem! And everything else works fine so far with the drawer navigation and the stack navigation altogether! Thanks again for your help, I just wanted to give you some feedback!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Gergana Georgieva

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code to keep your drawer hidden for required screen :

```
const Nav = createDrawerNavigator(

{
    Home: {
      screen: AppLogin,
      navigationOptions:{
        drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed',
        drawerLabel: <Hidden />
      },

    },
}
);
```

Your `Hidden` class should be as follows :

```
class Hidden extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

You can change the `drawerLockMode` value to keep the drawer opened or closed - Refer [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/drawerlayoutandroid.html#drawerlockmode) for different values.

Also you can refer this [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206280/componentwillmount-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-next-major-version-0) for avoiding the `componentWillMount` deprecation error. Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

With react-navigation V5 you can pass the `openByDefualt` prop

```js
 <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      openByDefault>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
 </Drawer.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

With react-navigation v6 all you need to do is pass `defaultStatus="closed"` prop directly to Drawer.Navigator. The app will always load with the drawer closed.