# React function isn't behaving as its expected to

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Heres a function from my react app:

```js
handleSubmit(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
    width: "",
    height: "",
    color: ""
  });
  console.log(this.state)
};
```

In my input, I set the value of input to the width, height and color. this `handleSubmit` function is happens when a form in filled.

But I have  set the state via `setState` before the `console.log` line. So this will replace the values from the form, before the `console.log` is called. I should get

```
{width :" ", height :" ", color :" "}
```

But instead, I get the value that was set by the input. But it seems like `setState` is only working when the full function is done, not before the log. Why?

Comment: @Pottay Rudra can you share your component?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58669497/5124488

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But it seems like setState is only working when the full function is done, not before the log. Why?

`setState` doesn't change the state immediately. Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

If you want to do something right after the state change, use a callback function.

```ts
handleSubmit(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
    width: "",
    height: "",
    color: ""
  }, () => {
    console.log(this.state)
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use functional setState rather than passing an object.  Instead you can pass a function to setState which takes the current state and props as arguments, this function returns an object which will be merged into the old state.

For example,

```
this.setState((state, props) => {
    return {
        counter: state.counter + 1
    }
});
```

Calls to setState get queued and then executed in the order they were called.  When they are executed the function receives the latest state instead of receiving old state.