# reactjs check for data update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, axios

I have `GUser` class, in my project to store data from GitHub-api and process them :

```
import axios from "axios";
export default class GUser {
    constructor(userName) {
        this.userName=userName;
        this.getUserData(this,userName);
    }
    getUserData(that, userName) {
        if(that.data===undefined)
        {
            axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/'.concat(userName))
                .then(function (response) {
                    that.data = response.data;
                    console.log(that);
                    return that.data;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(userName+ " got error " +error);
                });
        }
        else{return that.data;}
    }
}
```

I'm trying to sync pages, so in my `TestRender` I wrote :

```
import React from 'react';
import GUser from "../model/GUser";
class TestRender extends React.Component{
    userName='maifeeulasad';
    user=new GUser(this.userName);
    componentWillMount() {
        try {
            console.log(this.user.getUserData());
        }
        catch (e) {console.log(e);}
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        try {
            console.log(this.user.getUserData());
        }
        catch (e) {console.log(e);}
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default TestRender;
```

My target is to console log the data, as soon as it gets received.

**How can I do this ?**

Previously I used `componentWillMount` only, when I loaded data from the same script. It's currently giving me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`, maybe because of I haven't specified `data` as `state` in `GUser`, but it gets created through time right ?

Comment: not an answer please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206280/componentwillmount-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-next-major-version-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using object's attribute to store the state's component, that isn't good, because React will not to re-render the component when these values are updated.
Every instance of `TestRender` should have the same value of `userName` and `user` as attribute? These values are always the same? If not, use [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) for that.

Also, `componentDidMount` and `componentWillMount` will be called only when the component is being mounted, and at this moment you didn't finished the fetch, so you don't have yet the value to print. It's an async problem.

To handle with async challenges, I recommend to use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).